# Count categorical levels broken down into columns of aggregated table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a `data.table` containing a categorial variable and I am looking for an efficient way to count its categories in an aggregated table, whereas each category is broken down into columns.

Here's my data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2), 
                 y = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
> DT
    x y
 1: 1 A
 2: 1 A
 3: 2 B
 4: 1 A
 5: 1 A
 6: 1 B
 7: 3 B
 8: 3 B
 9: 3 A
10: 2 A
11: 2 C
```

Now I want to aggregate `DT` by `x` and receive a `data.table` with columns named after each category found in `y`, displaying the corresponding frequency:

```
   x A B C
1: 1 4 1 NA
2: 2 1 1 1
3: 3 1 2 NA
```

So far I only managed to solve this problem 'manually' by creating aggregations for each category, e.g. `DT[y == "A", .N, by = x]` and merging them together with a left join. I grazed the entire internet unsuccessfully for a much more dynamic solution such as a function that simply delivers the desired result just like:

```
DT1 <- aggfunc(DT, var = "y", by = "x")
```

Comment: You need `table()`, i.e. `table(DT$x, DT$y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. You basically want to reshape your counts:

```
# count cases
aggregated <- DT[, .N, by = .(y, x)]
# reshape to desired result
dcast(aggregated, formula = x ~ y, value.var = "N")
   x A B  C
1: 1 4 1 NA
2: 2 1 1  1
3: 3 1 2 NA
```

or, to directly write the function you desire:

```
aggfunc <- function(DT, var = "y", by = "x"){
  DT[, .N, by = c(var, by)]
  dcast(aggregated, formula = paste(by, "~", var), value.var = "N")
}

aggfunc(DT)
   x A B  C
1: 1 4 1 NA
2: 2 1 1  1
3: 3 1 2 NA
```

Comment: and also `dcast(DT, x ~ y, length, fill=NA_integer_)` without an intermediate step.

Comment: ah, interesting! dcast/melt are just so powerful functions :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using `summarise` and `pivot_wider`:

```r
DT %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  summarise(num = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=y, values_from=num) %>% 
  as.data.table
```

gives us

```r
   x A B  C
1: 1 4 1 NA
2: 2 1 1  1
3: 3 1 2 NA
```